# View seems to take up more than table cell size when using touchdragenter/exit/inside/outside

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, drag

I have a table with cells and each cell has a view constained to all 4 sides so the view is the size of the cell.  When I try to use touchdragenter/touchdragexit or touchdraginside or outside, it seems to think this view is like way taller.  It takes up like half the the cell above and cell below it.  I need to know when the touch exits one view (within one cell) and enters the next view (in the next cell).  I can't figure out how to get the views to register as the correct size.

Comment: Can you add some code or screenshot of the UITableView and the view you are using

Comment: It's just a table with 2 cells with the same view in each cell.  the view is constrained to be the size of the cell.  So as you touch one cell and drag over to the other one it should be showing that it is outside but it's not.  If I add more cells, it shows it's outside way past the edges of the cell.